# How to make a search bar page that connects to Firebase in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to implement a search bar with a table view into my app that searches data that is in Firebase storage. I am getting many errors while making this. Two of my errors have `Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'`, two have `Use of unresolved identifier 'inSearchMode'` and the next two are `Value of type 'Storage' has no subscripts` and `Value of type 'Storage' has no member 'filter'`. Ive been trying to figure out these errors for awhile now. Any assistance would be VERY appreciated! Thank you.

ps the ERRORS are shown as comments:

```
import Foundation
```

import Firebase

class SearchBarViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var data = Storage.storage()
var filteredData = [String]()
var isSearching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearching {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    return data.accessibilityElementCount()  //Might be a problem
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) is DataCell {

        let text: String!

        if isSearching {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {

                text = data[indexPath.row] //Value of type 'Storage' has no subscripts
        }
        cell.configureCell(data: text) //Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'

        return cell //Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'


    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()

    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

        inSearchMode = false //Use of unresolved identifier 'inSearchMode'

        view.endEditing(true)

        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true //Use of unresolved identifier 'inSearchMode'

        filteredData = data.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!}) //Value of type 'Storage' has no member 'filter'

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The error `Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'` caused because you are not actually creating any cell, you just type check `is DataCell`. In order to fix this this line should be

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as? DataCell { 
}
```

for the second issue, accessing `data[indexPath.row]`, since I don't know what data type it is, can't give you answer.

for the third issue, `Use of unresolved identifier 'inSearchMode'`, there is no variable declared for it. So it's expected. `isSearching` may be the one you should replace with it.

Comment: Thank you! the only problem I have left is regarding the Value of type 'Storage' has no member 'filter'

Comment: What's data type of `data` variable?. You can't use `filter` if it isn't defined. You can use filter on array cuz it's defined on `Collection`.

Comment: the data type 'data' was supposed to be the a reference to the data in my Firebase storage. Is that not what I can use it for?